# Why is physics pluralised? Why do some countries use 's' and others 'z' in some words?

Tags: grammatical-number, differences

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [***zation vs ***sation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/707/zation-vs-sation)
>   [What is the difference between a “singular noun” and a “plural noun treated as singular”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4656/what-is-the-difference-between-a-singular-noun-and-a-plural-noun-treated-as-si)

My question came from looking at this one [Why is "math" always pluralized in British English and singular in American English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/11830/4203). Why are words like Mathematics and Physics pluralised? On a side note i just noticied that i used an 's' instead of a 'z' in pluralised. Why do some countries use 's' and others 'z' in some words?

Comment: The question should be split in two, as you are asking two different things. The first part seems to duplicate questions already asked (including the one you are referring to).

Comment: See also [What is the difference between a “singular noun” and a “plural noun treated as singular”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4656/what-is-the-difference-between-a-singular-noun-and-a-plural-noun-treated-as-si).

Answer (score 0):

The OED generally prefers the 'z' over the 's' forms of words in modern English usage.  The 's' forms often relate to archaic Norman roots of words; and today, the 's' forms are normally found in areas where both French and English still mix (for example, in Canadian English).