# "Maths" for "Mathematics"; where does the S come from?

Tags: etymology, british-english, abbreviations

So in US English we shorten *mathematics* to *math*, and in the UK they say *maths*. Where does the 'S' come from in the UK version? For some reason I had it in my head that this was just because it's plural so you add the 's'; referring to multiple types of mathematics. But a question on another SE site just made me think about it, and it's actually not. "Mathematics" is both plural and singular:

> I am studying mathematics in school.
>
> There are many different types of mathematics.

So the 's' isn't a marker of a plural, so my mental-reasoning for why Brits use the 's' in *maths* is wrong.

The question becomes then, why *is* it there? I can't think of another abbreviation that pulls a letter from the end of the word like that ("math*******" vs "math*******s"). And this isn't just an extension of something used for similar words, because I don't think other subjects are abbreviated this way. So what is the reasoning behind it/where did it come from? Is it just what people started saying? Did a prominent person start using it? Did other people think (not very hard about it!) like I used to and jump to the *plural* conclusion? Or does it stand for something else?

To elaborate on my point about "not just adding the S for similar words", I'll take an example from a comment: "economics". In the US we shorten this to "econ". But I don't think they say "econs" in the UK, do they? So why just "maths"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Other academic field distinctions like math vs maths](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165995/other-academic-field-distinctions-like-math-vs-maths)

Comment: I know this is old and I'm not an English prof (singular ;P) but this came up in conversation the other day.
My reasoning was that Mathematics is a field encompassing a variety of techniques and principals etc. The same as the field of physics. Thus it's contracted, including the plural "s" in much the same way Laboratories (plural) is contracted to labs and congratulations to congrats/grats.
I would disagree that "there are many types of mathematics" - there may be several classes that cover different aspects of mathematics, but they don't teach different maths.

Answer (score 47):

Abbreviations and contractions of words follow many conventions, take for example the word *continued* I have seen it abbreviated/shortened/contracted or [clipped](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/apostrophe/contractions) in three ways.

- cont
- cont.
- cont'd

Mathematics can be similarly contracted

- math
- math.
- (math's) maths

Perhaps, originally, the written form with the apostrophe, *math's*, was more common in Great Britain but over time the apostrophe became obsolete. In fact the apostrophe in *math's* has no effect on its pronunciation. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the Oxford English Dictionary to confirm my suspicion that the term *math's* was ever used. 
The Online Etymology Dictionary instead states that the American *[math](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=math&allowed_in_frame=0)* first appeared in 1890 while the British *maths* is attested from 1911.
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbreviation) has this to say on contractions:

> An abbreviation is a shortening by any method; a contraction is a
>   reduction of size by the drawing together of the parts. **A contraction
>   of a word is made by omitting certain letters or syllables and
>   bringing together the first and last letters or elements;** an
>   abbreviation may be made by omitting certain portions from the
>   interior or by cutting off a part. A contraction is an abbreviation,
>   but an abbreviation is not necessarily a contraction.

Further on, Wikipedia explains

> In British English, according to Hart's Rules, the general rule is
>   that abbreviations (in the narrow sense that includes only words with
>   the ending, and not the middle, dropped) terminate with a full stop,
>   whereas contractions (in the sense of words missing a middle part) do
>   not.

[image]

Curious to see whether I could find the apostrophe version, I turned to Google Books and found to my surprise that [*math's*](http://books.google.it/books?id=nPw_AAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA39&dq=%22math%27s%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=juJ2U5LSLYKdO6nogSA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22math%27s%22&f=false) existed in the US, this example is dated 1836, and predates *Word Detective's* claim that the first instance of *math* appeared in 1847.

[image]

---

Larry Trask who was professor of Linguistics in Sussex University (UK) mentions the most common shortened forms where the apostrophe still survives.

> A few words which were contractions long ago are still conventionally
>   written with apostrophes, even though the longer forms have more or
>   less dropped out of use. There are so few of these that you can easily learn them all. Here are the commonest ones, with their original longer forms:
>
> - o'clock, *of the clock*
> - Hallowe'en, *Halloweven*
> - fo'c's'le, *forecastle*
> - cat-o'-nine-tails, *cat-of-nine-tails*
> - ne'er-do-well, *never-do-well*
> - will-o'-the-wisp, *will-of-the-wisp*

**EDIT**

Published in Richmond USA by William F. Richie, 1853-54, The *Merit Roll of the Cadets of the Virginia Military Institute, July 1853*   lists [math's](http://books.google.it/books?id=Aag0AQAAMAAJ&pg=RA2-PA64&dq=%22math%27s%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PgV3U_TLO4-h7AaZloDoCQ&ved=0CF8Q6AEwCjg8#v=onepage&q=%22math's%22&f=false) as the shortened form for mathematics twice!

[image]

---

**Personal Reflections**

As demonstrated in the excerpts I provided, it seems clear that the spelling convention for contracted words i.e., the use of the apostrophe for showing the omission of letters, was also used in the US. The shortened form *math's* was necessary in order to save space but for some reason the superfluous apostrophe and the letter -S were kept despite logic demanding that the word *math* was shorter. The question also arises whether this contracted word was ever actually *spoken by* Americans? My guess? Probably not, they chose not to  say *maths* **/maθs/** because it sounded plural and therefore opted for the clipped form, *math* **/maθ/** in speech. The British, being renowned traditionalists, decided to keep the "silent" apostrophe in speech and thus favoured the longer form *maths*.

Comment: Your hypothesis that *math* started life as *math's* and then dropped the apostrophe is appealing. However, the representativeness of your 1836 citation is open to question on the grounds that considerations of space and typography may have forced the typesetter to adopt the solution we can see above. When I viewed the full list of names in the Google Books text, I noticed that Edward Ward's name and credentials occurred in the only entry that was squeezed right up against the column divider. A few more instances of the same phenomenon would be helpful for strengthening the case you are making

Comment: @medica I will hunt out the other examples of math's which I did see but discarded. Yes, you're absolutely right, the apostrophe denotes possession, but nevertheless it is a shortening dated 1889. Interesting video, so the *math* 1847 reference belongs to OED. But she's wrong about how we shorten/abbreviate words, the last letter can and is often added see **Dr** with or without the period, **Rev'd** or **Revd** and **Gov't**.

Comment: The distinction between spoken and written expressions seems important here. I first learned about "maths" reading dialogue in British books and hearing it in British films and television. I cannot count the number of expressions commonly written as abbreviations but nearly always pronounced in full. A sampling: etc., Rev'd, Do. (see excerpt above: abbreviation of "Ditto"), Rt. Hon., Mr., Mrs., Dr., St., govt, dept., secy. In the face of that practice, knowing that "mathematics" has ever been abbreviated in writing as "math's" and "maths" doesn't explain to me why it is pronounced that way.

Comment: @JoanPederson are you saying you don't understand why Brits say /maθs/ the shortened form, and not the original form? Maths is quicker to say than mathematics, but by no means has the latter disappeared from the vernacular.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A - I'm just saying that observations about the spellings of abbreviations do not help explain the pronunciations of the abbreviated terms, as the examples I listed were intended to show. The posts about written abbreviations seem to me to be going off the main subject, which I find interesting.